Questions about showing $d_1+\cdots +d_n-n+1 \leq {\text{dim}}_k k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$.
The following are from Froberg's "Introduction to Grobner bases" , and Hungerford's undergraduate "Abstract Algebra" text, and also a continuation of this post
Background
Theorem 1: $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n]\backsimeq (k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}])[x_n]$
Theorem 2:  Let $K$ be an extension field of $F$ and $u\in K$ an algebraic element over $F$ with minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$.  Then
$(1)$ $F(u)\equiv F(x)/(p(x))$
$(2)$ $\{1_F,u,u^2,\ldots,u^{n-1}\}$ is a basis of the vector space $F(u)$ over $F$.
$(3)$ $[F(u):F]=n$.
Assumed Exercise: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal generated by monomials in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.  Show that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $k$ if and only if for each $i$ there is a $d_i>0$, such that ${x_i^{d_i}}\in \mathfrak{a}$.
Exercise: Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a monomial ideal such that $\{x_i^{d_i},\cdots,{x_n^{d_n}}\}$ is a part of a minimal system of generators for $\mathfrak{a}$, where $d_i$ are positive.  Show that
$$(LHS)\quad d_1+\cdots d_n-n+1 \leq {\text{dim}}_k  k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}\leq d_1d_2\cdots d_n\quad (RHS)$$
Questions
I am trying to do the above Exercise using the solution to Assumed Exercise above and basic abstract algebra knowledge.
Below is my attempted solution to the left hand side inequality:
Attempted Solution for $(LHS)$ inequality:
From Assumed Exercise above, we know that $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is a finite dimensional (quotient) vector space, hence we need to count the minimum number of basis elements. The ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is generated by $\{x_i^{d_i},\cdots,{x_n^{d_n}}\}$, so we can set $\mathfrak{a}=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle$, and $x_i^{d_i}\in \langle x_i \rangle$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots, n$.  Also, by Theorem 1 above, $k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_n]\backsimeq (k[x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}])[x_n]$, we can reduce to the case from $n$ indeterminates to the case of a single indeterminate for the vector space $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$.
So let $F= (k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]), u=x_i, F(u)=(k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}])(x_i),$ like the hypothesis of Theorem 2 above.  Using $(2)$ of Theorem 2, each $x_i\in \mathfrak{a}$ is a monomial of maximal (is it maximum or total?) degree $d_i$. Using $(2)$ of Theorem 2 one more time, there exist $\{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]},x_i,x_i^2,\ldots,x_i^{{d_i}-1}\mid i=1,2,\ldots n\}$ as a basis of the vector space $F(u)=(k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}])(x_i)$ over $\mathfrak{a}$.  There are $d_i$ number of elements in the basis $\{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]},x_i,x_i^2,\ldots,x_i^{{d_i}-1}\mid i=1,2,\ldots n\}$.
Since there are $i=n$ indeterminates of the $x_i$ and for each $x_i$, there are $d_i$ number of basis elements.
Hence there are $d_1+d_2+\cdots +d_n$ total number of basis elements.  However each basis contains the identity element $1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]}$, and they are all equal to each other, since the identity element of a vector space is unique.  Hence, the identity element has been double counted $n-1$ times.  So the dimension of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/\mathfrak{a}$ is at least $d_1+d_2+\cdots +d_n-(n-1)=d_1+d_2+\cdots +d_n-n+1$
Can someone comment on whether I proved the $\text{LHS}$ of the above Exercise correctly please?  I am not sure of the following two counting argument step is correct.  It has to do with my intepretations of meaning of $d_i$ for arriving at $d_1+\cdots +d_n$ and also and my understanding of the property of the identity elemetn to arrive at subtracting $n-1$.

(1) Using $(2)$ of Theorem 2, each $x_i\in \mathfrak{a}$ is a monomial of maximal (is it maximum or total?) degree $d_i$. Using $(2)$ of Theorem 2 one more time, there exist $\{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]},x_i,x_i^2,\ldots,x_i^{{d_i}-1}\mid i=1,2,\ldots n\}$ as a basis of the vector space $F(u)=(k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}])(x_i)$ over $\mathfrak{a}$.  There are $d_i$ number of elements in the basis $\{1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]},x_i,x_i^2,\ldots,x_i^{{d_i}-1}\mid i=1,2,\ldots n\}$.
Since there are $i=n$ indeterminates of the $x_i$ and for each $x_i$, there are $d_i$ number of basis elements.


(2) However each basis contains the identity element $1_{F=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots x_{i-1} x_{i+1}\ldots x_{n}]}$, and they are all equal to each other, since the identity element of a vector space is unique.

Thank you in advance

@GreginGre I have edited my post. I originally asked about both side of the inequality in the other post. I decide to break up the post and let the other post focus on the LHS and this one on the RHS to keep the post more focus on a single issue.  Also, in the other post, you have told me you have answered the RHS inequality in another earlier post.  I have not heard back from you about the LHS, that is another reason for me to split up that post.

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

@BillDubuque I have cited the portions of hte proof where I am not sure if the arguments are correct.
